# Msbuild: Filter itemgroup based on file contents

Tags: msbuild, itemgroup

I need to filter an ItemGroup (containing filenames) based on the contents of the file. But I cannot get this to work.

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <FilteredFiles Include="@(AllFiles)" 
      Condition="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(Identity)).Contains('searchText'))" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I get this error:

> error MSB4184: The expression "[System.IO.File]::ReadAl
> lText(%(Identity))" cannot be evaluated. Could not find file
> 'C:\builds\git\RadarTemp%(Identity)'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive the most compatible way would be to use an intermediate item:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AllFilesWithSearchResult Include="@(AllFiles)" 
    ContainsSearchText="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%(Identity)').Contains('searchText'))" />
  <FilteredFiles Include="@(AllFilesWithSearchResult->WithMetadataValue('ContainsSearchText','True'))"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That works really well - thanks!
So I can add random "metadata" (if that's the correct term) in an attribute? Never seen that before.

Comment: Yes you can add metadata and metadata-as-attribute (instead of sub-elements) was added for .NET Core MSbuild projects a few years ago